# Loading template on page load through state - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application, I want the nested view `list-patents.htm` to load when the index page loads.

My main nav is on my `index.htm`, with two nav items `transactions` and `patents`.

If you were to click on `patents`, a further two sub-menu items would load: `list patents` and `add patents`. Here you can then navigate to `list-patents.htm` which I want to act as the landing view.

I have tried two methods:

- `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");` which I couldn't get to work.
- This method (which is in my script) loaded the nested view, but failed to load its parent nest view, the nav menu.

  `.state("index",
  {
      url: "",
      templateUrl: "templates/list-patents.htm",
  })`

I want to keep the navigation in its own view, as I don't see the point of creating duplicate code.

Any ideas how on page load, it loads the `patent-nav.htm` and it's nested view `list-patents.htm`? Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment', 'ui.router']);


app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {

    $stateProvider
    .state("index",
    {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: "templates/list-patents.htm",
    })
    .state("patents", {
        url: "/patents",
        templateUrl: "templates/patent-nav.htm",
        controller: "patentCtrl"
    })
    .state("patents.list", {
        url: "/list-patents",
        templateUrl: "templates/list-patents.htm",
        controller: "patentCtrl"
    })
    .state("patents.add", {
        url: "/add-patents",
        templateUrl: "templates/add-patent.htm",
        controller: "patentCtrl"
    })
```

**Views**

**index**

```
<main class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a ui-sref="patents">Patents</a>
            <a ui-sref="transactions">Transactions</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
    <section ui-view>

    </section>
</main>
```

**patent-nav**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="patents.list">List patents</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="patents.add">Add patent</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>
```

**list-patents**

```
<div>
//just a load of content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
$urlRouterProvider
                  .when('', '/parents/list-patents')
                  .when('/', '/parents/list-patents')
                  .otherwise('/parents/list-patents');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Worked